# gcc - leverage compiler to aid in code instrumentation

Tags: c++, gcc, instrumentation, qnx

**BACKGROUND**

I'm developing on [OMAP 5 (ARM)](http://www.ti.com/product/OMAP5432) and using a QNX `gcc`-based C++ compiler.

I know about [the ability of gcc to insert a custom entry/exit callback for each function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) but I'd like to have more info than that.

**PROBLEM**

For starters, I want to instrument every control-flow statement

```
void func()
{
    if(bob == 9)
    {

        bob = 55;   
    }
    else
    {
        bob = 101;
    }
}
```

Would become

```
void func()
{
    if(bob == 5)
    {
        MACRO(0x1433) //0x1433 = ID for this particular if-statement
        bob = 55;   
    }
    else
    {
        MACRO(0x3243) //0x3243 = ID for this particular else-statement
        bob = 99;
    }
}
```

I know I could do the parsing myself but for more complex statements, it would get messy.

**QUESTION**

The gcc compiler already does the parsing of the code in the process of compilation.

Is there any way I can leverage some intermediate output so I can more easily identify control-flow statements?

Obviously there's the preprocessed output but that only resolves macros

Comment: although you could get intermediate files (see `-save-temps`) this hardly would help you.

Comment: @Serge I don't mean those kind of files I mean a mapping of control-flow statements to line number

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature. BTW, what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Serge whitebox/branch coverage testing

Comment: I don't see a point for this, but you are the boss...

Comment: @Serge you don't see a point for whitebox or branch-coverage testing?

Comment: No, I don't. Never had a need.

Comment: @Serge never having a need is not the same as not seeing the point. Develop a 2mil line embedded GUI and you'll see the need

Comment: I said: you are the boss.

Comment: I am doing embedded development for past two decades on devices with very limited capabilities and in most cases without even theoretical possibility to connect a gdb to device. So, I know what I am speaking about.

Comment: What about gcc's builtin code-coverage support via `-fprofile-arcs` and `gcov`?

Comment: Parsing the code to produce this seems like an impossible task.  What about the ternary operator?  Switch statements?  With fallthrough?  Function calls via function pointer lookup?  Compiler instrumentation seems like the only solution

Comment: @Peter according to [docs, the data is only saved 'When the compiled program exits'](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html). Does that mean only when `int main()` exits? We have event loops so `exit` would only happen when the event loop would be gracefully shut down.

Comment: @Peter is there a way to limit the size of the `-fprofile-arcs` `.gcda` files? Our tests could be running for days before the program `exits`.

Comment: Not sure about the details, you might need to hack around the compiler source to figure out non-standard usage.  Still, I think this will be a more fruitful path than trying to write your own C++ parser.  You said you're looking for compiler-aided instrumentation of branch statements.  It's called `-fprofile-arcs`

Comment: See for example: http://sysrun.haifa.il.ibm.com/hrl/greps2007/papers/gcov-on-an-embedded-system.pdf

Comment: @Peter yes I agree `-fprofile-arcs` is the solution. Is there really no documentation other than the `gcc` source code?

Comment: @Peter does `-fprofile-arcs` merely record the number of times a certain path is executed? I would actually need sequence i.e. line X, line Y, line Z, etc